# is there mouseClicked or keyPressed in perl?

Tags: perl, keypress, mouseclick-event

I remember when I would code in Java, there would be a command that would sense a mouse-click or when a key was pressed. Could you somehow do the same thing but in perl? Something like this

```
print "\n", "Press the 'I' key for instructions", "\n"; 
my $a = readline STDIN;

chomp $a;

#This next line is what is what I'm thinking of
     if (keyPressed eq "I" || "i")
     {
     print "\n", "Instructions: blah, blah, blah", "\n";
     }
print "\n", "Click your mouse if you want to exit the instructions", "\n";
     while (mouseClicked = True)
     {
     print "\n", "Press the 'I' key for instructions", "\n"; 
          if (keyPressed eq "I" || "i")
          {
          print "\n", "Instructions: blah, blah, blah", "\n";
          }
     print "\n", "Click your mouse if you want to exit the instructions", "\n";
     }
```

Something like that. Main question: Is there any mouseClicked or keyPressed (Java) in perl?

Comment: Please visit following [web page](https://www.perl.com/pub/2005/08/11/win32guitest.html/) for an answer.

Comment: Terminal control is provided by [Term::ReadKey](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadKey), for example.  That will allow you to recognize keystrokes etc.  As for a mouse, you'll need a GUI for that and then of course there's a lot of ways to handle mouse clicks and way more.  Major libraries are `Gtk3`, `Qt`, and `WxWidgets`. (Just like in Java, where you can't tell a mouse click if you run in a terminal.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Term::RawInput](http://metacpan.org/pod/Term::RawInput).
Here is some basic example:

```
use Term::RawInput;

my $prompt='PROMPT : ';
my ($input,$key)=('','');
($input,$key)=rawInput($prompt,0);

print "\nRawInput=$input" if $input;
print "\nKey=$key\n" if $key;

print "Captured F1\n" if $key eq 'F1';
print "Captured ESCAPE\n" if $key eq 'ESC';
print "Captured DELETE\n" if $key eq 'DELETE';
print "Captured PAGEDOWN\n" if $key eq 'PAGEDOWN';
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
use Term::ReadKey; 
ReadMode "cbreak"; 
binmode(STDIN); 
sysread(STDIN,$k,1); 
print "k=$k\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

Mouse tracking and key presses is a feature of GUI environment. You have to choose what you will be using to program GUI.

For keyboard keystroke you will require to use [Term::ReadKey](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadKey)  or [Term::RawInput](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::RawInput).

If you want some interaction with a user and not just key presses then perl script can take following *shape*

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $input = '';

say '
    Please type one of: help, instructions, quit
';

do {

    help()          if $input eq 'help';
    instructions()  if $input eq 'instructions';

    print "Input > ";
    $input = <STDIN>;
    chomp $input;
    $input = lc $input;

} while( $input ne 'quit' );

say '
Thank you for dropping by, hope to see you soon again.

Good by ...
';

sub help {
    say '
    This is an example of help for user of this program.

    Please provide some information for purpose of the program
    and instructions how to use it....
    ';
}

sub instructions {
    say '
    This is an example of instructions assistance page.

    Please give a description of available instructions to user
    of this software....
    ';
}
```